# How to study a series with upper bound in the summand?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show that, given $(n,N) \in \mathbb{N}^2$, $N \geq 2$, $n<N$, $x_n \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\left|x_n\right|\leq 1$, CV denoting convergence:
\begin{equation}\label{appeq:toprove}
 S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{x_n}{n}\quad \text{CV} \implies T_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{x_n}{N}\quad \text{CV} \quad\quad (*)
\end{equation}

as it seems to be true (at least with the $x_n$ that I deal with, more about them at the end of the question). I was considering using Abel's test to prove it, using [this kind of demonstration](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/335_12/Abel.pdf). The short version of the proof would be:

1. Let $b_n = \frac{x_n}{n}$, $a_n = \frac{n}{N}$
2. $S_N = \sum b_n$ converges by hypothesis
3. $a_n$ is monotone (increasing) and bounded ($a_n < 1)$
4. Thus according to Abel's test, $\sum a_n \cdot b_n = T_N$ converges.

However, an essential part of the argument would be that $a_n$ is bounded and $a_n < 1$, and I am not at ease with this. Indeed, I kind of feel it weird to have a summand inside the series and I do not even know how to write properly $a_n$'s convergence.

I would tend to say - intuitively, and whatever that mean - that:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow N\\ N \rightarrow + \infty} a_n = 1
\end{equation}

But I do not know how this combines with the above-mentioned proof... Actually **I am a bit lost since I never studied this kind of series wherein the upper bound is also inside the summand**. Any help, clarifications, or explanations on that matter would be gratefully welcome.

Alternatively, if anyone can prove $(*)$ it would also be great !

---

**Off-topic:** Very lousely related question (actually the only one I could find mixing upper bounds and summand): [Limit of a series with upper bound in the summand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057282/limit-of-a-series-with-upper-bound-in-the-summand)

**About $x_n$:** $x_n$ are in deed random variables, actually a product of cosines whose arguments depend on $n$ and on other random variables. While their true distribution is not known, it could be assumed that they are kind of evenly distributed on $[-1,1]$. *Note:* actually, $\sum b_n$'s convergence is thus an almost-sure convergence.

Comment: This question has been asked twice in a short period of time. One of both repeated questions should be deleted

Comment: Very weird, I only edited it... Will delete the other one. EDIT: strange bug, the other one is deleted, sorry about the noise.

Comment: I think it has already been deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k/k$ be the partial sum, then

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{x_n}N=S_N-\frac1N\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}S_n. \tag{$\star$}$$

Since $S_n\to S$ for some $S\in\mathbb C$, the mean $\sum_{n=1}^NS_n/N$ also converges to $S$ by the [Cesaro mean theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_Mean), hence $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{x_n}N\to0$.

---

Problem of Abel's test:

In Abel's test, we concluded that the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^N|b_n(a_n-a_{n+1})|$ converges because it is increasing in $N$ and bounded above. However, with $b_n=x_n/n$ and $a_n=n/N$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^N|b_n(a_n-a_{n+1})|=(1/N)\sum_{n=1}^N|x_n|/n$ is not necessarily increasing in $N$ since $1/N$ is decreasing, so you are right that we need to be careful using Abel's test in this case.

At least, we can use the idea of Abel's test to obtain $(\star)$, which is basically [summation by parts](https://brilliant.org/wiki/summation-by-parts/).

Answer (score 0):

Although Mengchun Zhang's answer is synthetic and addresses both aspects of the original question, I wanted to add a more detailed version of the proof for the records.

---

Lets demonstrate that

\begin{equation}
\boxed{
 S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{x_n}{n}\quad \text{CV} \implies T_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{x_n}{N}\quad \text{CV} \quad\quad (*)}
\end{equation}

Let $a_n = \frac{x_n}{n}$

Then $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_n$ and $S_{n+1} - S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k = a_n = \frac{x_n}{n}$

And thus $x_n = n \cdot \left( S_{n+1} - S_n \right)$

Then $T_N = \frac{1}{N} \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n \cdot \left( S_{n+1} - S_n \right)$

We can then rewrite $n \cdot \left( S_{n+1} - S_n \right) = n \cdot S_{n+1} - (n-1)\cdot S_n - S_n$, in order to make a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) in $T_N$ as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
T_N &= \frac{1}{N}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left( n \cdot S_{n+1} - (n-1)\cdot S_n \right) - \frac{1}{N}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} S_n\\
&= \frac{1}{N}\cdot \left( (N-1)\cdot S_N - 0\cdot S_1 \right) - \frac{1}{N}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} S_n \\
&= \frac{N-1}{N}\cdot S_N - \frac{1}{N}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} S_n\\
&= S_N - \frac{1}{N}\cdot S_N - \frac{1}{N}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} S_n\\
&= S_N - \frac{1}{N}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{N} S_n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

We can thus use Cesàro's theorem (or lemma, [depending](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_de_Ces%C3%A0ro#Suites_convergentes) on [the sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), also, formulation may vary), which can be formulated as:

> **Cesàro's theorem:**
> Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ a sequence of real or complex numbers. If it converges towards a limit $\ell$, then the sequence $(c_n)$ of its Cesàro means, defined by $c_n = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$ also converges, and its limit is $\ell$.

And back to $T_N$:

\begin{equation}
\underbrace{T_N}_{\rightarrow 0} = \underbrace{S_N}_{\;\;\rightarrow \ell \\ \;\;\;\text{by} \\ \text{hypothesis}} - \underbrace{\frac{1}{N}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{N} S_n}_{\;\; \rightarrow \ell \\ (\text{Cesàro})}
\end{equation}

And thus we finally demonstrated that:

\begin{equation}
\boxed{
 S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{x_n}{n} \xrightarrow[N \rightarrow \infty]{} \ell \implies T_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{x_n}{N} \xrightarrow[N \rightarrow \infty]{} 0
}
\end{equation}

Which is an even stronger result than $(*)$.